npm is not installing properly with nodejs in windows
I have downloaded and installed NodeJs in my machine. Then to confirm that the installation is successfully done I tried for npm -v, and it successfully shown the version. But whenever I am trying for npm version, it  is throwing error. I have reinstalled nodejs at least 3-4 times, but same thing is happening, it is showing error can not find module '../../package.json'. So I am not able to create the react project as well.


did you uninstall it completely? did you remove nodejs related folders before reinstalling it? Like, C:\Program Files\nodejs, C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm and C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache? Did you remove these files?

Have you checked that the path of nodejs is present in the system variables of your environment variables?

I have uninstalled it from control panel only. Do I need to manually remove the folders? @GpAdhikari

How to check that? @PiyushPamnani

@SoumiGhosh I think you have to remove those folders manually. Also if you want to check youe environment variables, go to search and type, environment variables, click Edit the system environment variables, at the bottom right, click environment variables..., click the PATH and edit to view. You should see C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm

Try this and see if it works.

Why don't you try reinstalling your npm globally using this command npm install -g npm

I have tried this already. It is also not working. Throwing the same error.
